# Setting max and min user input in React form

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I need to limit the user's input to this field below to be between 0 - 1. I don't want the user to input any number that is less that zero or greater than 1. How will this be implemented in React form.

```
<Form.Group controlId="username">
      <Form.Label>Learning Rate</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="number"
        step="any"
        placeholder="Enter Learning Rate"
        name="lr"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </Form.Group>
```

Comment: I'd expect to handle the validation inside of `handleInputChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have it right, just do this

```
 <input
        type="number"
        step="any"
        min="0"
        max="1"
        value={numb}
        onChange={(e) => setNumb(e.target.value)}
      />
```